# solidity, how to send eth to a contract in the same tx you create it

Tags: solidity, contract-development

actually i'm creating a new contract with `new Contract(params)`
but how to send eth in the same time (in the same tx like geth does) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat `(new Contract)` as a function, as such:

```
(new Contract).value(wei)(params)
```

Comment: Additionally, the constructor should be payable